# React state changed not re rendering child

Tags: reactjs

I Would like to bind two child field together.
I have created change handler in parent class and passing state value in props of child.
whenever i type something in textfield, Parent state and child props are updated i can see that in react dev tool, but child state is not reflected.

Below is my code

```
class Parent extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: "test"};
        this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
    }

    changeHandler(value){
        this.setState({value: value});
    }

    render(){
        return (
                <div>
                    <Child value={this.state.value} change={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <Child value={this.state.value} change={this.changeHandler}/>
                </div>
                );
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
        this.state = {value: this.props.value};
    }

    changeHandler(e){
        this.setState({value:e.target.value});
        this.props.change(e.target.value);
    }

    render(){
        return (
                <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
                );
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: why does the child need state at all? Can it not just use the prop?

Comment: the child dont need any state, we can use `this.props.value` directly for the value in input field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are using

```
class Child extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
        // ...............  
        this.state = {value: this.props.value};
    }
    // ... 
}
```

Your internal `this.state.value` is set only "once" on component mount phase.
(*That means, whenever `Parent -> this.state.value` changes and causes the `Child` components to re-render, `this.state = {value: this.props.value};` won't be invoked again*)

Instead of using the state in Child component, use the `this.props.value` directly on your `<Input />` field.

```
<input type="text" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
```

So the flow is, someone types something in `Child.input`, which tells `Parent` to update the state, and the change is trickled back down to your `Child -> this.props.value`.

And then you notify Parent by calling the passed `this.props.changeHandler`.

So the final, `Child` component would look like following.

```
class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
    }

    changeHandler(e){
        this.props.changeHandler({value:e.target.value});
    }

    render(){
        return (
          <input type="text" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
        );
    }

}
```

If you use the ES6 "[arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)" syntax, you can make it smaller, removing the need for `this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this)`.
(*It's because an arrow function doesn't create its own `this` but uses calling context's `this`*)

```
class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    changeHandler = (e) => {
        this.props.changeHandler({value:e.target.value});
    }

    render(){
        return (
          <input type="text" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
        );
    }

}
```

Or you can call it directly from `onChange`.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.props.changeHandler}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

We can go one step further by converting it to a [Function Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) (NOT "Functional" component because it doesn't have anything to do with Functional Programming)

```
function Child({ value, changeHandler}) {
  return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={changeHandler} />
}

// or
const Child = ({value, changeHandler}) => 
  <input type="text" value={value} onChange={changeHandler} />
```

And when you use `const Child = ...`, make sure that it's declared BEFORE `Parent`. But when you use `function Child`, it can show up before or after `Parent` due to how JavaScript hoisting works.

Lastly, no change in `Parent` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `componentDidUpdate`

```
class Parent extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: "test"};
    this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
}

changeHandler(value){
    this.setState({value: value});
}

render() {
    return (
            <div>
                <Child value={this.state.value} change={this.changeHandler}/>
                <Child value={this.state.value} change={this.changeHandler}/>
            </div>
            );
    }
 }

class Child extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
    this.state = {value: this.props.value};
}


changeHandler(e){
    this.setState({value:e.target.value});
    this.props.change(e.target.value);
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(prevProps.value !== this.props.value) {
      this.setState({value: this.props.value});
  }
}

render(){
    return (
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
            );
}

}
ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Each child component has its own independent state. If you want the value to be shared between the two you remove it from state in the children and just use this.props.value in the children. Then value is only mutable in the parent.